# Turning a dataframe/dataset in R into a time series

Tags: r, time-series

I have the following problem. Lets say that I am studying the inflation rates of different sectors of the economy as following:

```
Category 2020 2021 2022
Food     1.5   2.0   3.0 
Gas.     1.0   1.2.  2.5
Rent.    2.0.  3.0.  2.8
```

I would like a method so that I can import the whole dataset into R and use the `tseries` package to carry out time-series economic analysis.

Much thanks in advance.

I used the `ts()` and `read.ts()` commands but they didn't provide what I wanted

Answer (score 0):

It's better if you can show the output you got and the desired output. It may be that you need the long format first to get a time index column and a value column, then create the time-series object per below?

`tsibble` is a good option for a grouped time-series.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(tsibble)

df <- tribble(
  ~Category, ~`2020`, ~`2021`, ~`2022`,
  "Food", 1.5, 2.0, 3.0,
  "Gas", 1.0, 1.2, 2.5,
  "Rent", 2.0, 3.0, 2.8
)

df |> 
  pivot_longer(-Category, names_to = "year", names_transform = as.numeric) |> 
  tsibble(index = year, key = Category)
#> # A tsibble: 9 x 3 [1Y]
#> # Key:       Category [3]
#>   Category  year value
#>   <chr>    <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1 Food      2020   1.5
#> 2 Food      2021   2  
#> 3 Food      2022   3  
#> 4 Gas       2020   1  
#> 5 Gas       2021   1.2
#> 6 Gas       2022   2.5
#> 7 Rent      2020   2  
#> 8 Rent      2021   3  
#> 9 Rent      2022   2.8
```

<sup>Created on 2024-03-07 with [reprex v2.1.0](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>